# Finite set of rank $\alpha$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Defining the rank function $\in$-recursively as $\text{rank}(x)=\bigcup\{\text{rank}(y)^{+}\mid y\in x\}$ for a set $x$, for which ordinals $\alpha$ does there exist a finite set of rank $\alpha$? And what happens if we require the set to be transitive?

Comment: Why do you ask, and what did you try to do to solve this? It's not very hard. Also note that if $\gamma$ is an infinite ordinal $\gamma^+$ usually denotes the next *cardinal* after $\gamma$, and not the next ordinal. You **should** write $\operatorname{rank}(y)+1$ instead.

Comment: I asked because I just wasn't sure whether I had done it correctly. It was part of an exercise in P.T.Johnstone's book which I am reading at the moment.

Comment: This would be valuable information with regards to how some people (e.g. myself) would answer. You should include some summary of the results that you arrived to.

Comment: Okay, I will do so next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it works for any successor ordinal $\alpha^+$, since you can consider $x=\{\alpha\}$.

If you require $x$ to be transitive and finite, then it is clear by induction that it has finite rank, so only the finite ordinals $\alpha$ work.

Comment: Note that under this definition $\operatorname{rank}(\alpha)=\alpha$. So your answer is wrong for a lot of ordinals.

Comment: ah yes it is only true for the successor ordinals, sorry.